# How to make y-scales in ggplot in R follow similar numbering format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis-labels, facet-wrap

I would like to change the format of the `y-axis` numbers such that the axis-es follow similar numbering format. right now `Facet A` is plain while `Facet B` is scientific. I understand there are large difference in the values of the two `facets` which is why i use `log scale` make the low values more visible. I used `labels = "scientific"` to force the scale being scientific but is giving me error. here is my code- any help would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF = data.frame(A = runif(8000, 100,800), B = runif(8000, 0, 10), C = 1:8000)
DF_g = gather(DF, key = "Variable", value = "Value", - C)
ggplot(DF_g, aes(x = C, y = Value, color = Variable))+
  geom_boxplot(lwd = 1)+facet_wrap(~Variable, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

The Figure i get from the code is
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `scientific_format()` from `scales`:

```r
ggplot(DF_g, aes(x = C, y = Value, color = Variable))+
    geom_boxplot(lwd = 1)+facet_wrap(~Variable, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y")+
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::scientific_format())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks- is there a way to force the breaks on `y-axis` being either 3 or 5 in numbers. right now it varies (i.e., for A there are 3 ticks while for B i see 5 ticks).

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `scales::log_breaks(n = 5)` that seems to work ... to get 3 ticks on each facet... Not sure about the rationale of this finding ... Otherwise, maybe you can pass your own sequence of breaks to make sure you have 3 or 5 on each facet

Comment: giving me this error `Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths`

Comment: Adding this ‘scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::log_break(n=5))’ gave me the error.

Comment: Sorry in fact it is two different arguments. `scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10", labels = scales::scientific_format(), breaks = scales::log_break(n=5))`

Comment: Thanks @dc37- I tried the above suggestions but its giving me `Error: 'log_break' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales'`. I `re-installed` `scales` package to see the updated version would work but giving me the same error.

Comment: Adding s at the end of `break(s)` removed the error but didn't forced the `y-axis` to be partitions in equal `ticks`. I am going to accept the answer as it you have answered my initial question- the rest were added details. Thank you.